# How to tell if git branch has been fully merged after squash

Tags: git, merge, git-squash

When merging branches with `--squash`, git does no longer seem to be able
to determine whether a branch has been fully merged. How can I quickly check this with existing git commands?

To reproduce, create a new git repository:

```
$ mkdir tmp
$ cd tmp
$ git init
$ echo "bla" > ans
$ git add .
$ git commit -m "First commit"
```

Create branch `new-branch` with commits:

```
$ git checkout -b new-branch
$ echo "blabla" >> ans
$ echo "blupp" > zwa
$ git add .
$ git commit -m "Commit on new-branch"
```

Create branch `another-branch` with commits:

```
$ git checkout master
$ git checkout -b another-branch
$ echo "test" >> ans
$ echo "three" > dra
$ git add .
$ git commit -m "Commit on another-branch"
```

Merge:

```
$ git checkout master
$ git merge --squash new-branch
$ git commit -m "Squash new-branch"
$ git merge --squash another-branch
$ git mergetool
$ git commit -m "Squash another-branch"
$ git clean -f
```

Both branches have been merged. I should be able to delete them now, right? Unfortunately, no:

```
$ git branch -d new-branch
> error: The branch 'new-branch' is not fully merged.
> If you are sure you want to delete it, run 'git branch -D new-branch'.
$ git branch -d another-branch
> error: The branch 'another-branch' is not fully merged.
> If you are sure you want to delete it, run 'git branch -D another-branch'.
```

I *could* use option `-D`, but usually someone else merges my stuff, and I want to check
whether the merge was successful. Trying to use `git diff`:

```
$ git diff new-branch
$ git diff ..new-branch
$ git diff ...new-branch
$ git diff new-branch..
$ git diff new-branch...
```

All the statements above yield a non-empty diff. Another attempt:

```
$ git branch --merged
> * master
```

The two branches do not appear in the list of merged branches, so this didn't work either.

How can I tell whether the branches have been merged?

Comment: Repeat the merge with `--no-commit`, and if you see that no changes are missing (and all conflicts have been resolved in the expected way), your branch has been merged.

Comment: This does not work nicely. git first thinks there is another conflict. git mergetool then sees everything is fine. I would wish to be able to tell in a single command without having to call mergetool.

Comment: Then you can't. Change your workflow to not use `--squash`.

Comment: @j6t I would agree. `--squash` might be git's number one cargo cult trope. I don't say it's always bad practice of course, but we see so many people here with problems down the line with this feature, who when asked about why squashing in the first place answer with "because I guess I should" or "because they said so"... I don't assume anything about you specifically, @digory doo, please don't take it for you, it's just a general observation.

Answer (score 7):

You cannot get what you want.  You *can* get several things that may or may not be good enough.  In particular, if you use a plain `git merge` (with `--no-ff` if/when required), Git records the *commits*.  Git isn't really concerned with files, as it's about *commits*.  Git isn't really very much concerned about *branches* either: it's still all about *commits*.

#### Illustration, with graph-drawings

Using your example, creating a new empty repository and stopping at this point:

> ```
> $ git commit -m "First commit"
> ```

you now have a repository with exactly one commit in it.  That one commit has some big ugly hash ID, but I'll just use the letter `A` to stand in for it.  The repository now has one named branch, `master`, which holds the hash ID of this one commit `A`, so we can draw it like this:

```
A   <-- master (HEAD)
```

Now we run your second series of commands:

> ```
> $ git checkout -b new-branch
> ```

At this point we have:

```
A   <-- new-branch (HEAD), master
```

> ```
> $ echo "blabla" >> ans
> $ echo "blupp" > zwa
> $ git add .
> $ git commit -m "Commit on new-branch"
> ```

This creates new commit `B`, dragging the name `new-branch` forward:

```
A   <-- master
 \
  B   <--  new-branch (HEAD)
```

Now we use your third series of commands (I'll trim one down a bit):

> ```
> $ git checkout -b another-branch master
> ```

This switches back to commit `A`, creates a new branch name pointing to it, attaches `HEAD` to the new branch, and leaves us with:

```
A   <-- another-branch (HEAD), master
 \
  B   <--  new-branch
```

> ```
> $ echo "test" >> ans
> $ echo "three" > dra
> $ git add .
> $ git commit -m "Commit on another-branch"
> ```

This creates third commit `C`, dragging the name `another-branch` forward to it:

```
  C   <-- another-branch (HEAD)
 /
A   <-- master
 \
  B   <--  new-branch
```

Now we take on the hard part, the two `merge` commands.  We start with:

> ```
> $ git checkout master
> ```

This extracts the contents of commit `A` into the index/staging-area and your work-tree, and attaches the name `HEAD` to the name `master`:

```
  C   <-- another-branch
 /
A   <-- master (HEAD)
 \
  B   <--  new-branch
```

> ```
> $ git merge --squash new-branch
> ```

This does a merge operation that consists of diffing commit `A` vs commit `A` (which shows no differences of course) and then commit `A` vs commit `B` (which shows some differences).  The changes discovered in these two diffs get combined—without any conflict, since one set of changes is "do nothing"—and Git stops short of making a new commit, so we need:

> ```
> $ git commit -m "Squash new-branch"
> ```

which *does* make the new commit.  I'll call this `D`:

```
  C   <-- another-branch
 /
A---D   <-- master (HEAD)
 \
  B   <--  new-branch
```

Note that commit `D` has *no* backwards-looking connection to commit `B`; it remembers *only* the hash ID of existing commit `A`.  Had you used:

```
git merge --no-ff new-branch
```

to make `D`, we'd have a connecting line (should be an arrow but arrow fonts don't always work right on every browser) going down-and-right from `D` to `B`:

```
A---D
 \ /
  B
```

but we don't.

Next:

> ```
> $ git merge --squash another-branch
> ```

This time the merge operation consists of diffing commit `A` (the merge base) with commit `D`, to see what *we* changed, then diffing commit `A` vs commit `C` (the tip commit of `another-branch`), to see what they changed.  The merge is actually conflicted—we both changed the file `ans`, in lines that abut at the end of the file—so most forms of merge will stop here with a conflict.  Hence you needed:

> ```
> $ git mergetool
> ```

to resolve the conflict, though we could do that in shell with:

```
$ cat << END > ans
bla
blabla
test
END
$ git add ans
```

(you can substitute whatever you want for the merge result in the here-document section before the `END`).  The last step here is to commit the merge.  Since it *is* a squash-merge, rather than a real merge, once again we *do not* have a backwards link to commit `C`, even though we *used* commit `C` to do the merge:

> ```
> $ git commit -m "Squash another-branch"
> ```

This makes new commit/snapshot `E`, so let's draw that:

```
  C   <-- another-branch
 /
A---D--E   <-- master (HEAD)
 \
  B   <--  new-branch
```

Note that new commit `E` has no connection back to `C`.  Using the name `master`, Git starts at commit `E`, walks back to `D`, then walks back to `A`.  Commit `A` has *no* parent—it's the very first commit we ever made, after all—so the action stops at this point.  Commits `B` and `C` are not found in this process.

#### Why `git branch -d` fails

If we don't use `git mergetool`, we don't need `git clean` to clean up its junk files, so I'll skip over that and proceed to:

> ```
> $ git branch -d new-branch
> > error: The branch 'new-branch' is not fully merged.
> > If you are sure you want to delete it, run 'git branch -D new-branch'.
> ```

What this is telling you is that from commit `E`—where you are now—there's no way to find commit `B`.  That's true; we will not find `B` in a walk from `E` back to the root.  In fact, the name `new-branch` is the *only* way we have to find commit `B`.  (Remember, `B` stands in for some random-looking hash ID that we would never be able to guess.)  If we *do* delete the name `new-branch`, we will lose commit `B`.

Since Git is all about commits, losing a commit would be bad.  Git won't discard the name, and hence lose the commit, unless you force it.

The same goes for commit `C`, find-able *only* through the name `another-branch`.  The `git branch -d` command will refuse to delete it as commit `C` is not an ancestor of current commit `E`.

If we'd used regular `git merge`—with `--no-ff` the first time, since otherwise Git would have cheated with a fast-forward instead of a merge—we'd have, at this point, *this* graph:

```
  C___  <-- another-branch
 /    \
A---D--E   <-- master (HEAD)
 \ /
  B   <--  new-branch
```

Now each request, to delete the names `new-branch` and `another-branch`, would be "safe", because starting at commit `E`, Git can walk back to commits `D` *and* `C`.  From `D`, Git can walk back to commits `A` *and* `B`.  Commits `B` and `C` are therefore on branch `master`, as well as being on branches `new-branch` and `another-branch` respectively.  It's safe to delete the *name* `new-branch` as commit `B` is protected by being on `master`.  It's safe to delete the *name* `another-branch` as commit `C` is protected by being on `master`.

#### Commits are history

Fundamentally, using `git merge --squash` is a way to tell Git: *I'm going to throw away some commits / history.*  If we have:

```
...--A--B--C--D--E   <-- branch1 (HEAD)
            \
             F--G--H   <-- branch2
```

and we run `git merge --squash branch2`, we'll make a *new* commit on the current branch `branch1` that is the result of combining the diff from `C` to `E`—what *we* did on `branch1`—with the diff from `C` to `H`—what *they* did on `branch2`.  After successfully making this new commit:

```
...--A--B--C--D--E--FGH   <-- branch1 (HEAD)
            \
             F--G--H   <-- branch2
```

the *only* sensible thing to do with `branch2` is to delete it.  Git doesn't immediately delete it because we might have some other plans for some of its commits—for instance, maybe we want to cherry-pick `G` or `H` as a new commit in some *other* branch—but eventually we should kill it off.  But our new `FGH` combined commit *doesn't* remember the hash of commit `H`, so deleting the name `branch2` *will* lose commits `F`, `G`, and `H`; so `git branch` requires that we force this deletion.

Note that if there is some additional commit *beyond* `H`, find-able through some other name:

```
...--A--B--C--D--E--FGH   <-- branch1 (HEAD)
            \
             F--G--H   <-- branch2
                    \
                     I--J   <-- branch3
```

this additional *name* will keep commit `J` alive, and `J` will keep `I` which keeps `H` which keeps `G` which keeps `F`.  Here, `git branch -d branch2` will still fail from `branch1`—commit `H` is not an ancestor of commit `FGH`—but will succeed when run from `branch3`.

The precise definition of when a branch-name delete must be forced has evolved a bit over time.  Git used to just use the current commit (`HEAD`) and the branch-tip to decide if a deletion was safe.  Now it also considers the branch's *upstream* setting, if the branch has one.  If the branch tip commit is an ancestor of the branch's upstream's tip commit, but not of the current commit, Git now deletes the branch with a warning.  The commits are safe—they're protected by the *upstream* name, at least for the moment—but Git isn't sure you really meant to do this, so it prints a warning including the hash ID that was stored in the branch name, to allow you to restore the branch name using that hash ID.

Comment: Thanks for this very elaborate answer. However, it still lacks a practical answer how I can solve my problem. The best answer so far seems to be, _don't use squash in the first place_.

Comment: The point of all this is just that: there *isn't* a solution. If you don't like what squash does, don't squash. :-) Hence the very first sentence, "you cannot get what you want"...

Answer (score 2):

> How can I tell whether the branches have been merged?

By squashing the commit range and using `git cherry master <squashed commit>`.[1]

(**Update**: see “Addendum 2” for a script that gives you the “squashed merge”, if it exists)

Your example is a special case though, since there is only one commit on
`new-branch` which is not also in `master`. See section prefix “Checking
for a squash merge” for how to deal with that (which also goes into `git cherry` and `git cherry-pick`).

#### A more interesting history

But say you have three commits on `new-branch` which are not in
`master`. Here’s a modification of your setup script:[2]

```
t=$(mktemp -d)
cd $t
git init
main=$(git var GIT_DEFAULT_BRANCH)
echo "bla1" > ans
git add .
git commit -m "A"
echo "bla2" >> ans
git add .
git commit -m "B"
git checkout -b new-branch
echo "la1" >> ans
git add .
git commit -m "X"
echo "la2" >> ans
git add .
git commit -m "Y"
echo "la3" >> ans
git add .
git commit -m "Z"
git checkout $main
git merge --squash new-branch
git commit -m "C"
```

`master` (or whatever `git var GIT_DEFAULT_BRANCH` is):

```
A -- B -- C
```

`C` is the squashed commit.

`new-branch`:

```
A -- B -- X -- Y -- Z
```

`X`, `Y`, and `Z` have been squashed into `C` on `master`.

Now, first a sanity check: none of the commits of `new-branch` are
recognized as having anything to do with `master`:

```
$ git cherry $main new-branch
+ 684749f894128d5c7d80070f945805c164b998d4
+ 2a52d29d77182ad0c4ef8bceca876428d339b106
+ bb090a348919af77b1bfa8fafd2649418574b36f
```

The plus-sign means “no” (see next section for an explanation).

But now we can squash the branch and see:

```
$ # Assuming that we can do a checkout
$ git checkout --detach new-branch
$ # Squash the commits[3]
$ git reset --soft $(git merge-base $main @) && git commit -m 'squash'
$ # Set a temporary tag so that I can refer to it later
$ git tag squash
$ git cherry -v $main @
- 5e0021b2ca26acbe8d10aaf0d99fe45b89831331 squash
```

Yes! The squashed version of the branch is in `master`. You can
force-delete your branch, if you want.

… But what if `master` keeps going? Will `git cherry` still report that
`new-branch` is “merged”? Yes:

```
$ git checkout $main
$ echo 'la4' >> ans
$ git add .
$ git commit -m "D"
$ git checkout squash
$ git cherry -v $main squash
- 81e7f1c8947d8390cdfe4e8f98462341ca552e4d squash
```

#### Merge conflicts

The original setup with three branches seems to involve a merge
conflict:

```
git mergetool
```

So how do you find “squash merges” in the face of conflicts using this
approach with `git cherry`?

You cannot. That’s impossible.

If you want to stick to squashing as well as being able to find them
later, then you *need* to only do `git merge --squash` if it doesn’t
conflict. And if it *does* conflict you need to (1) rebase the branch on
`master` and fix the conflicts (2) retry the squash-merge.

If you have merge conflicts then the conflict resolution will
necessarily give a different “change”/diff than what you would have
gotten if the squash merge applied cleanly. So it’s impossible for `git cherry` to figure out whether or not your branch has been squashed to
`master`.

#### Checking for a squash merge with only one commit on the branch

Back to the original example:

```
$ git checkout new-branch
$ git cherry -v master
- 38decef0caa57abd0babf7bd2582d3af7a02abd2 Commit on new-branch
```

The output here is a bit backwards: the minus sign means that it has
been applied to “upstream” (`master`) and that *you* in turn can drop
it (you don’t need to keep it since it’s been applied to upstream); if
it wasn’t applied then there would be a plus sign there instead
(meaning: keep this one ’cause it ain’t been applied yet).

You *could* try to apply it with `git cherry-pick`, though. But it
would skip it:

```
$ git checkout master
$ git cherry-pick new-branch
On branch master
You are currently cherry-picking commit 38decef.
  (all conflicts fixed: run "git cherry-pick --continue")
  (use "git cherry-pick --skip" to skip this patch)
  (use "git cherry-pick --abort" to cancel the cherry-pick operation)

nothing to commit, working tree clean
The previous cherry-pick is now empty, possibly due to conflict resolution.
If you wish to commit it anyway, use:

    git commit --allow-empty

Otherwise, please use 'git cherry-pick --skip'
```

`git cherry-pick` uses `git cherry` (or equivalent) to check if the
“patch” has been applied it, and skips applying it if it has.

```
# Can just back out of this redundant cherry-pick
git cherry-pick --abort
```

#### Addendum 1: commits versus patches

Commits are snapshots; two commits that introduce the same change may
have different hashes (I guess “OID” is the correct term).

But `git cherry` doesn’t care about that. It only cares about the
changes. Namely:[4]

```
The equivalence test is based on the diff, after removing whitespace and
line numbers. git-cherry therefore detects when commits have been
"copied" by means of git-cherry-pick(1), git-am(1) or git-rebase(1).
```

And for the “more interesting history” setup we have:

```
git diff $main~ $main
$ diff --git a/ans b/ans
index 637f070..afd7d7d 100644
--- a/ans
+++ b/ans
@@ -1,2 +1,5 @@
 bla1
 bla2
+la1
+la2
+la3
```

And for the branch:

```
$ git diff $(git merge-base $main new-branch) new-branch
diff --git a/ans b/ans
index 637f070..afd7d7d 100644
--- a/ans
+++ b/ans
@@ -1,2 +1,5 @@
 bla1
 bla2
+la1
+la2
+la3
```

And for that temporary squash:

```
$ git diff squash~ squash
diff --git a/ans b/ans
index 637f070..afd7d7d 100644
--- a/ans
+++ b/ans
@@ -1,2 +1,5 @@
 bla1
 bla2
+la1
+la2
+la3
```

The changes are all the same.

#### Addendum 2: script for finding the squash merge

Using `git checkout` and `git reset` isn’t convenient. Let’s use `git patch-id` instead:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Find out if a commit has been “squash merged” upstream
# The name is a homage to `git-when-merged`: https://github.com/mhagger/git-when-merged

upstream=$1
yours=$2

# Get the patch-id of the diff of the squash
patch_id=$(git diff $(git merge-base $upstream $yours) $yours \
    | git patch-id --stable | cut -d' ' -f1)
git rev-list $yours..$upstream | while read -r line ; do
    other_patch_id=$(git diff $line~ $line | git patch-id --stable | cut -d' ' -f1)
    if [[ $patch_id = $other_patch_id ]]; then
        printf "$line\n"
        exit 0
    fi
done

# Not found
exit 1
```

I’ve tested this on some of my “squash merges” in the repository at $dayjob.

This might be very slow if you have a decent-sized history and if the commit isn’t squashed yet. (I have only tested “happy cases”.) It could perhaps be expanded to use `--since` on `git rev-list`.

#### Notes

1. All of this uses `git patch-id` (or equivalent). I would recommend
   (just in case + for reproducibility) that you set:

   ```
   git config --global patchid.stable true
   ```

   In order to make sure that you’re not using the deprecated, legacy
   behavior.
2. I will also omit the third branch for simplicity (I didn’t understand
   that there was supposed to be a merge conflict (`git mergetool`)
   until I saw that torek pointed it out.) You didn’t say anything about
   possible merge conflicts being significant. But see the “Merge
   Conflict” section.
3. [Taken from](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5201642/1725151)
4. `man git cherry` as of `git version 2.40.0`

Answer (score -1):

Your branches were successfully merged. You are getting below message 
**error: The branch 'new-branch' is not fully merged.**
Because code is not pushed to remote branch yet.
Please push the code after that git branch -d new-branch command will work without any error.

The -d option stands for --delete, which would delete the local branch, only if you have already pushed and merged it with your remote branches.
The -D option stands for --delete --force, which deletes the branch regardless of its push and merge status, so be careful using this one!

Comment: That's not right. Try my example and push it to some server. git will still think the branches are not merged. The reason is that `squash` creates new commits and does not link the old commits.

Answer (score -1):

You can print only the merged branches with:

```
git branch --merged
```

So if you see your branch there when you are on the master branch, it means it is merged.

The reason why you don't see it is because that is what "--squash" is for. It does not merge at all, it includes the changes and then you commit. It is confusing but there is actually no merge. Everything happens as if you typed the changes that happened to be similar in another branch.

The good thing to note though is that "mergetool" works anyway. I didn't know that.

Now it would perfectly work with "diff", but the problem is that you included 2 branches, and with a conflict on top of it. So you will not get a result.

I also understand you are looking for an answer and my advice would be to clone your master branch somewhere else, do a real merge of these branches, and then do a diff between your real working repo and your clone.

Does that make sense? Then you'll know for sure.

Comment: Nope, neither of the branches are listed. git thinks they are not merged. Did you try my example?

Comment: My apologies, I've edited my answer with more details to be explicit and provided a workaround.